# Created a child page and got a 500

Tags: django

As the title states, I created a 'child' page and BAM: 500. Following is what I believe is the actual traceback, and a bit of information on the 500 page that I believe is germane to the topic.

Is there anything I can do? I attempted to manually remove the page afterwards to no prevail. (Don't worry, I modified a *copy* of the database).

```
AssertionError at /admin/cms/page/
Negative indexing is not supported.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.56.101:8080/admin/cms/page/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: AssertionError
Exception Value:    
Negative indexing is not supported.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __getitem__, line 157
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3

Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.56.101:8080/admin/cms/page/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'cms',
 'menus',
 'mptt',
 'south',
 'cms.plugins.text',
 'cms.plugins.picture',
 'cms.plugins.link',
 'cms.plugins.file',
 'cms.plugins.snippet',
 'cms.plugins.googlemap',
 'sekizai',
 'registration',
 'cms_themes']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  307.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  197.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/admin/pageadmin.py" in changelist_view
  657.         cl.set_items(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/admin/change_list.py" in set_items
  198.                     children[-1].last = False
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __getitem__
  157.                 "Negative indexing is not supported."

Exception Type: AssertionError at /admin/cms/page/
    Exception Value: Negative indexing is not supported.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your version of `django-mptt` is `0.5.1`.

Comment: I ran 'sudo pip install django-mptt --upgrade' on my ubuntu machine and got 'Requirement already up to date: django mptt in *', Should I try to manually reinstall this? Or is it dangerous to do so?